# Google Maps - Create marker on click on blank map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, marker

I run into a problem with blank maps and maps with existing markers.

A user can add a new marker to a map or move an existing marker by dragging or clicking anywhere on a map. This is no problem as long as there already is a marker.

This is an example of my code with two maps. One without a marker, the other one with a marker.

```
<script>
  function initMap() {
    var myLatLng_1 = {lat: 20.782, lng: 10.177};
    var myLatLng_2 = {lat: 50.864, lng: 20.996};

    var myOptions_1 = {zoom: 6, center: myLatLng_1, draggableCursor: 'crosshair'};
    var myOptions_2 = {zoom: 6, center: myLatLng_2, draggableCursor: 'crosshair'};

    var myMap_1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap_1'), myOptions_1);
    var myMap_2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap_2'), myOptions_2);

    var myMarker_2 = new google.maps.Marker({position: myLatLng_2, map: myMap_2, draggable: true});

    google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker_2, 'dragend', function() {
      myMap_2.panTo(myMarker_2.getPosition());
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(myMap_1, 'click', function(e) {
      myMarker_1.setPosition(e.latLng);
      myMap_1.panTo(myMarker_1.getPosition());
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(myMap_2, 'click', function(e) {
      myMarker_2.setPosition(e.latLng);
      myMap_2.panTo(myMarker_2.getPosition());
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APlkSyA9oDVEF5v74FiMMk-9VOnlRrgGO8z_Yayo&callback=initMap"></script>
```

How do I have to modify my "click" addListener so that it creates a new marker if there is no one but also let me set an existing marker to a new position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to check if the variable is defined, if it is, set the position, otherwise, create the marker, then set its position.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(myMap_1, 'click', function(e) {
  if (!myMarker_1)
    myMarker_1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: myMap_1,
      draggable: true
    });
  myMarker_1.setPosition(e.latLng);
  myMap_1.panTo(myMarker_1.getPosition());
});
google.maps.event.addListener(myMap_2, 'click', function(e) {
  if (!myMarker_2)
    myMarker_2 = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: myMap_2,
      draggable: true
    });
  myMarker_2.setPosition(e.latLng);
  myMap_2.panTo(myMarker_2.getPosition());
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/6vpeg578/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var myMarker_1;
  var myLatLng_1 = {
    lat: 20.782,
    lng: 10.177
  };
  var myLatLng_2 = {
    lat: 50.864,
    lng: 20.996
  };

  var myOptions_1 = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: myLatLng_1,
    draggableCursor: 'crosshair'
  };
  var myOptions_2 = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: myLatLng_2,
    draggableCursor: 'crosshair'
  };

  var myMap_1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap_1'), myOptions_1);
  var myMap_2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap_2'), myOptions_2);

  var myMarker_2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng_2,
    map: myMap_2,
    draggable: true
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker_2, 'dragend', function() {
    myMap_2.panTo(myMarker_2.getPosition());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(myMap_1, 'click', function(e) {
    if (!myMarker_1)
      myMarker_1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: myMap_1,
        draggable: true
      });
    myMarker_1.setPosition(e.latLng);
    myMap_1.panTo(myMarker_1.getPosition());
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(myMap_2, 'click', function(e) {
    if (!myMarker_2)
      myMarker_2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: myMap_2,
        draggable: true
      });
    myMarker_2.setPosition(e.latLng);
    myMap_2.panTo(myMarker_2.getPosition());
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#myMap_2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
}

#myMap_1 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id='myMap_1'></div>
<div id='myMap_2'></div>
```